# В ситуациях применения &, | к boolean значениям, они перестают быть побитовыми?

Tags: java, syntax

То есть сравнивают по такой же технологии как и &&, ||, лишь с небольшим изменением (и справа и слева проверяется)?

5 > 1 & 6 >3; //true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верно, операции `&` и `|` применимы к булевым значениям, но имеют небольшое, хоть и существенное отличие от своих логических аналогов: [short-circuit_evaluations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) в этом случае не работают.

При

```java
s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(0) == 'x'
```

или

```java
s.length() == 0 || s.charAt(0) != 'x'
```

правые части выражения не будут вычислены, если левой части уже достаточно для получения результата.

Если же заменить операторы на `&` и `|` соответственно - выражение будет вычислено целиком, и в данном случае приведет к ошибке, если строка будет пустой.

Кроме того, приоритеты операторов тоже отличаются: `true | true && false` даст `false`.